# Repeating task Using nested Loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to use the following code to draw 9 circles horizontally and 9 circles vertically on a canvas.

I have inserted a nested for-loop for this operation, but unfortunately I am having only one horizontal line of 9 circles.

Can anyone help please?

```
<canvas id="sCanvas" width="550" height="1000"> </canvas>

<script>
    var randomColour;
    var size;
    var xPos;
    var yPos;
    var ctx;
    var i;
    var j;


    function drawCircle(size, x, y, randomColour) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, randomColour);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = randomColour;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = randomColour;
    }

    var c = document.getElementById("sCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    xPos = 20;

    yPos = 20;

    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        randomColour = "hsl(" + 360 * Math.random() + ",50%,50%)";
        drawCircle(30, xPos, yPos, randomColour);
        xPos += 50;

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            randomColour = "hsl(" + 360 * Math.random() + ",50%,50%)";
            drawCircle(30, xPos, yPos, randomColour);

            xPos += 50;
        }
        yPos += 30;

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your xPos after every iteration, otherwise you just keep advancing right. This will work:

```
for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    xPos = 20; //Moved this in here from outside
    randomColour = "hsl(" + 360 * Math.random() + ",50%,50%)";
    drawCircle(30, xPos, yPos, randomColour);

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        randomColour = "hsl(" + 360 * Math.random() + ",50%,50%)";
        drawCircle(30, xPos, yPos, randomColour);

        xPos += 50;
    }
    yPos += 50;

}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q9czt0v/)

Comment: Thanks I didn't expect it to be so easy but it works.